# What GUI libraries are available for Blackberry OS 5.0

Tags: java, user-interface, blackberry

what GUI libraries are available for Blackberry OS 5.0 development?

Answer (score 1):

Blackberry uses it's own Library for GUI components, the [BlackBerry JDE](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javadevenv.jsp).

RIM has a page for new BlackBerry developers who are just getting started: [Getting Started](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/started/)

I find this book pretty useful to explain about BlackBerry development:
[Learn Blackberry Games Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430227184)

Comment: it seems only suitable here is WebWorks SDK since it allows to create UI of any complexity, not like 'native' library which is really limited to very basic UI components.

Answer (score 1):

I suggested technomage answer. And also i suggest [LWUIT](http://lwuit.java.net/) framework. I used this framework for developing blackberry applications.  For more info see [this page](http://www.pader-sync.com/lwuit-for-blackberry-and-android.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link, i will have a look at it and compare with functionality provided by Blackberry WebWork mixed with PhoneGap framework...